# Jquery Submit form and refreshes page

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, grails, jquery-ui-dialog

I've met into some problems with the Jquery, this are my codes from Jquery:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var username = $( "#username" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),

      allFields = $( [] ).add( username ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $("#success").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 700,
          width: 500,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             "Okay": function() {
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                location.reload();   
             }


         }
        });
    $( "#create1" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 700,
      width: 500,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( username, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( username, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );





          if ( bValid ) {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              $( "#success" ).dialog( "open" );
              $('#createUser').submit();

          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }

      }

    });

    $( "#create" ).button().click(function() {
        $( "#create1" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
```

So the problem here is, I want to do a form submit PLUS a refresh after its form is submitted. However, the form is being submitted before it can even do a refresh. I've tried doing AJAX but it isn't working. Prior to why I have to refresh after submitting the form is because I have a list of added things in a table and I have to refresh and show the user the updated list. You guys have any idea on how do I do that? Thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you actually stop the form from submitting.  That would look something like `$(form).on('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: So you want to refresh the page after the form submits? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Yes, I want the form to submit to the controller -> add user -> refresh page and show updated list.

Comment: @ExplosionPills is there a way that I can send the form plus refreshing the page after that? Like probably a delay of 2 second to a refresh of the page.

Comment: If you submit a form to the current page, then the page will refresh. Leave the form `action` blank (or set it to itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question is bit confusing since if you use ajax there is no need to refresh the page...

anywasy why don't you submit your form whn success dailog `OK` button is pressed since even create1 dialog is calling success dailog...that way you will get success dialog to.. form will get submitted after success and page will  refresh..

```
$("#success").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 700,
      width: 500,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
         "Okay": function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            //location.reload();   
            $('#createUser').submit(); //here
         }


     }
    });
```

note: remove the form submit in create dialog.

Comment: I want a refresh after the submit. Let me post you the photos on why I want a submit.

Comment: if your are submitting the form..then it will get refreshed.. jus call the same view in your controller once you have done the things with the posted data

Comment: Okay I know what to do already. Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: I just added a redirect to the same view in my controller and its fixed. Thank you so much for the advise